# Update user's profile page: fails to update user info in the database

Tags: php, html, mysql, session

I have no clue why this isnt working
here is the back end php:

```
include_once 'dbh-inc.php';

if (isset($_POST['edit'])) {

    $first = mysqli_real_escape_string( $conn , $_POST['first']);
    $last = mysqli_real_escape_string( $conn , $_POST['last']);
    $uid = mysqli_real_escape_string( $conn , $_POST['uid']);
    $city = mysqli_real_escape_string( $conn , $_POST['city']);
    $region = mysqli_real_escape_string( $conn , $_POST['region']);
    $country = mysqli_real_escape_string( $conn , $_POST['country']);
    $id = $_SESSION['u_id'];



     mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE users SET user_first = '$first', user_last = 
    '$last', user_uid = '$uid', user_city = '$city', user_region = '$region', 
     user_country = '$country' WHERE user_id = $id");



    }

   header("Location: ../my-profile-edit.php");


     ?>
```

when i put a: mysqli_error() underneath the query, it says the $id is undefined, which is beyond me because, that variable works on all the other pages for grabbing the current sessions users ID. this is proof of code in the login page:

```
$_SESSION['u_id'] =$row['user_id'];
```

here is the html code for the update profile page:

```
<?php include_once 'Header.php'; 

$uid = ucfirst($_SESSION['u_uid']);

//THIS CODE ONLY EDITS THE VISIBLE PORTION OF A USERS PROFILE//
?>


<form class="edit-profile" action="includes/edit-profile-inc.php" 
method="POST">
<table width="398" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
     <td width="82" valign="top"><div align="left"> <?php echo $uid ?> </div> 
</td>
    <td height="26" colspan="2"><input type="text" name="uid" 
placeholder="New Username"></td>
    <td><div align="right"><a href="index.php">logout</a></div></td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td width="129" rowspan="5"><img src="<?php echo $picture ?>" width="129" 
height="129" alt="no image found"/></td>
    <td width="82" valign="top"><div align="left">FirstName:</div></td>
    <td width="165" valign="top"><input type="text" name="first" 
placeholder="New First name"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td valign="top"><div align="left">LastName:</div></td>
    <td valign="top"><input type="text" name="last" placeholder="New Last 
Name"></td>
  </tr>

<tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top"><div align="left">City:</div></td>
     <td valign="top"><input type="text" name="city" placeholder="New City"> 
 </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
 <tr>
    <td valign="top"><div align="left">Region: </div></td>
    <td valign="top"><input type="text" name="region" placeholder="New 
 Region"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td valign="top"><div align="left">Country:</div></td>
    <td valign="top"><input type="text" name="country" placeholder="New 
Country"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr> 
    <td valign="top"><div align="left">About me: </div></td>
    <td valign="top">
      <input type="text" name="about" placeholder="About me">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><button type="submit" name="edit">Update profile</button></td>
     </tr>
   </table>
    </form>
    <p align="center"><a href="index.php"></a></p>
     <?php
      include_once 'Footer.php';
     ?>
```

so yeah I'm at odds as to why this isn't working, any help would be extremely appreciated!

Comment: Long shot, but try encapsulating the ID in single quotes. ex: `'$id'`

Comment: does not work unfortunately :(

Comment: Also a tip for debugging queries: try submitting the query via mysql workbench, phpMyAdmin, or whatever you use. When you submit the query replace the PHP variables with sample data to see what errors it throws. Usually makes clear it for me.

Comment: Check if your session has been started. You may have missed `session_start` prior to the insert. If session is started, throw a `var_dump($_SESSION);` in there to see what is available.

Comment: To clarify Howard's comment, you tried encapsulating $id in single quotes in the query, right? `...WHERE user_id = '$id'");`

Comment: mopsyd you were correct, silly mistake, i thought it would be included because it was on the front end page. thanks so much guys!

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Accidentally unescaped data is a serious risk. Using bound parameters is less verbose and easier to review to check you’re doing it properly.

Comment: If you're just getting started with PHP and want to build applications, I'd also strongly recommend looking at various [development frameworks](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) to see if you can find one that fits your style and needs. They come in various flavors from lightweight like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to far more comprehensive like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/). These give you concrete examples to work from and much stronger guidance on how to write your code and organize your files.

Comment: //PREPARED STATEMENTS//
     $sql = "INSERT INTO users ('user_first, user_last, user_uid, user_city, user_region, user_country')
  VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";
  $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
  if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
   echo "SQL error";
  } else {
   mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssss", $first, $last, $uid, $city, $region, $country);
   mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
  }    .... is adding this what you mean, so that i defend against injection?